# How can I combine WordPress and React?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I tried some combinations like Gatsby, Netlify, Next.js, etc. to create a workflow for developing WordPress websites using React. I'm not satisfied with the solutions. There are too many dependencies and services look not mature yet. Is there a good practice for combining WordPress with React?

Comment: React can be a single JavaScript file loaded inside your wordpress theme... but this depends on what you want to do with React.
Can you detail you needs a little?

Comment: Thank you Luca. Basicly I'm trying to create a boilerplate theme for my future "porfotlio website developments".

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress does have implements its [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) service, you can just build a normal React or use SSR with NextJS or Gasby, so that wp will be acting like a backend for the website.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Create A React App (industry standard at this point) https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

than from there, take your minified JS and CSS files and point your PHP HMTL file to use those JS and CSS files.   From that point, PHP Wordpress templates just need a div ID to bind your react UI to.